# I’m trying to use UITextChecker to verify the existence of a word. I wrote a small test program that is giving me baffling results

Tags: swift, uitextchecker

Below is test code I wrote in a Swift Playground. It shows UITextChecker is not working reliably.

```
   import UIKit

func validWord(word: String) -> Bool {
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: word.utf16.count)
    let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")
    
    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}

for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" {
    let word = String(repeating: char, count: 5)
    print("\(word): \(validWord(word: word) ? "Valid" : "Misspelled")")
    print("\(word.uppercased()): \(validWord(word: word.uppercased()) ? "Valid" : "Misspelled")")
}
```

Here are the results:
aaaaa: Misspelled
AAAAA: Valid
bbbbb: Misspelled
BBBBB: Valid
ccccc: Valid
CCCCC: Valid
ddddd: Valid
DDDDD: Valid
eeeee: Misspelled
EEEEE: Valid
fffff: Misspelled
FFFFF: Valid
ggggg: Misspelled
GGGGG: Valid
hhhhh: Misspelled
HHHHH: Valid
iiiii: Valid
IIIII: Valid
jjjjj: Misspelled
JJJJJ: Valid
kkkkk: Misspelled
KKKKK: Valid
lllll: Valid
LLLLL: Valid
mmmmm: Valid
MMMMM: Valid
nnnnn: Misspelled
NNNNN: Valid
ooooo: Misspelled
OOOOO: Valid
ppppp: Misspelled
PPPPP: Valid
qqqqq: Misspelled
QQQQQ: Valid
rrrrr: Misspelled
RRRRR: Valid
sssss: Misspelled
SSSSS: Valid
ttttt: Misspelled
TTTTT: Valid
uuuuu: Misspelled
UUUUU: Valid
vvvvv: Valid
VVVVV: Valid
wwwww: Valid
WWWWW: Valid
xxxxx: Valid
XXXXX: Valid
yyyyy: Misspelled
YYYYY: Valid
zzzzz: Misspelled
ZZZZZ: Valid

I would expect consistent results over the entire alphabet.

Comment: Words in all uppercase are assumed to be valid initials and i, v, x, l, c, d, and m are all roman numerals so they are valid in a series while lowercase.  Can't tell by your formatting if there are any outside of those that are appearing valid, but if there are, it's more likely actually a valid series of characters rather than not working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Makes perfect sense.